# AsyncTask params и поворот экрана

Tags: java, android

Имеется класс наследующий от `AsyncTask` и реализованный во фрагменте с флагом setRetainInstance(true);

```
public class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Поток запускается из активности и в качестве params передаются ссылки на строки

```
fragment.startAsynk(edittext1.getText().toString(), edittext2.getText().toString());
```

Вопрос в следующем. Уничтожится ли активность в данном случае при повороте экрана во время выполнения `doInBackground`? Ведь получается, что поток хранит ссылку на строки привязанные к активности пока выполняется `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Уничтожится ли активность в данном случае при повороте экрана во время выполнения `doInBackground`? Ведь получается, что поток хранит ссылку на строки привязанные к активности пока выполняется `doInBackground`.

Да, уничтожится. Тот факт, что Вы передаете куда-то какие-то данные, связанные с активити никак не влияет на ее жизненный цикл (но, в случае, если где-то будет хранится ссылка на инстанс самой активити, это повлияет на сборку мусора).

Comment: *Активити не уничтожится в том случае, если ссылка на нее будет где-то храниться* 

Вы уверены? Не путайте чистку мусора с `onDestroy()`, который вызывается при повороте в любом случае.

Comment: @Barmaley не в любом, гарантировано вызывается только `onPause()`, но про чистку мусора и уничтожение - согласен.

Comment: @Barmaley, Да, изъяснился несколько непонятно. В первом случае под `уничтожится` имелся ввиду вызов `onDestroy()`, а во втором – очистка мусора.

Comment: Ну вот - теперь плюсую :)